# Print two or more outputs from functions side by side in python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm a little new to Python and I was wondering how you would present more than one output side by side if it was part of different functions. So for a simple example:

```
def function1():
    print("This is")

def function2():
    print("a line")

def main():
    function1()
    function2()

main()
```

If I do this it would print:

```
This is 
a line
```

But how would I adjust it to print out like this:

```
This is a line
```

EDIT: I noticed .end function would help here but what if I had a long list of item? It doesn't appear to work in that scenario. So for example what if my two outputs were:

```
252
245
246
234
```

and

```
Bob
Dylan
Nick
Ryan
```

and I wanted to join the two so it would be like:

```
252 Bob
245 Dylan
246 Nick
234 Ryan
```

Comment: The duplicate link here was simply wrong; I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: I noticed .end function would help here but what if I had a long list of item? It doesn't appear to work in that scenario.

Perhaps something like this?

```
def function1():
    print('Work It', end='')
    yield
    print('Do It', end='')
    yield
    print('Harder', end='')
    yield
    print('Faster', end='')
    yield


def function2():
    print('Make It', end='')
    yield
    print('Makes Us', end='')
    yield
    print('Better', end='')
    yield
    print('Stronger', end='')
    yield


def main():
    generator1, generator2 = function1(), function2()

    while True:
        try:
            next(generator1)
            print(' ', end='')
            next(generator2)
            print()
        except StopIteration:
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Output**

```
Work It Make It
Do It Makes Us
Harder Better
Faster Stronger
```

Comment: This works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use in function print end=""
Such this

```
def function1():
    print("This is", end=" ")

def function2():
    print("a line", end="")

def main():
    function1()
    function2()

main()
```

Comment: I see. What if each output was a descending list of items, though and I wanted to keep them like that to make columns?

Comment: Then I would suggest to collect the data first, and postponing the printing to a separate function that prints it all.